# Calendar Item from Lotus Notes client are saving as draft

Tags: c#, calendar, lotus-notes

I am creating Lotus Notes calendar item using C# application. When I save the calendar item in the calendar folder of NSF file, its also getting stored in the Draft folder as well. Here is my sample code.

```
NotesDocument calDoc      = NotesDatabase.CreateDocument();

calDoc.AppendItemValue("Form", "Appointment"); 
.
.
.//Assiging values to CalDoc
.
.

calDoc.ComputeWithForm(true, false);
calDoc.Save(false, false, true);  //On execution of save statement it saves calender in
                                  //drafts as well as in calendar folder 
calDoc.PutInFolder(path, true);
```

I have changed all boolean values while saving dalendar document but getting same result. Any help on this is greatly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Mayuresh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an item `ExcludeFromView` with value "D". This prevents the appointment from showing up in Draft folder.

```
calDoc.ReplaceItemValue("ExcludeFromView", "D");
```